# Understanding the Calculation Process of BERT Model Loss in Sequence Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am seeking clarification on the process flow for calculating the loss in a BERT model for sequence classification. I have tokenized data and a code snippet as follows:

```
tokenized_data1= {'input_ids': array([[  101, 19278, 15091, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101, 19278, 15091, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101,  8084, 11318, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        ...,
        [  101,  7708, 14381, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101,  5379,   787, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101, 22327,  1987, ...,     0,     0,     0]]),
 'token_type_ids': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]),
 'attention_mask': array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]])}


labels1=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(3e-5))
model.fit(tokenized_data1, labels1)

1/1 [==============================] - 40s 40s/step - loss: 0.5368
```

In the above, I am using a pretrained transformer model. The tokenized data has input_ids of shape 32, so while fitting the model, only one run gets executed, and the default batch size is 32.

During training, the loss value is reported as 0.5368. I am attempting to understand the steps leading to this specific loss value. My understanding so far involves obtaining the logits from the model and applying a cross-entropy loss function. However, my attempt yielded a different loss value (0.6769). Here is the snippet of my attempt:

```
# Obtaining logits
outputs = model(input_ids=tf.constant(tokenized_data1['input_ids']),
                attention_mask=tf.constant(tokenized_data1['attention_mask']))
logits = torch.Tensor(outputs.logits.numpy())
labels1=torch.tensor(labels1)

# Calculating loss using cross-entropy loss function
loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, 2), torch.tensor(labels1).view(-1))
```

The computed loss (0.6769) differs from the reported loss (0.5368).

I need guidance on understanding the correct process flow for obtaining the reported loss value and identifying any errors in my approach. Thank you.